# MacOS El Capitan icon change

Tags: terminal, dock, macos, icon

I having a big question with some icons i change. I managed to move into rootless by restarting and *CMD + R* to boot into Recovery, then utilities and terminal. On terminal i wrote

> csrutil disable

to disable S.I.P. , after that , regular boot and opened Iconlite.app to change the icons, i changed almost all xd then i repeat the process but this time with

> csrutil enable

this time to get S.I.P. and the system normal. Well, i'd change a lot of them included that HD icons that appears on *Boot + OPT/ALL* to select in which SO i want to start. 
The question is that in my user some icons still being the same BUT on guest user that icons are actually changed, i just wanna know why or how i should get that change on my user as well. 
The next image shows what i mean on the Finder, Safari, Calendar are different 
**I just forgot and i didn't change the System Preferences icon

[image: icons comparative]

Thanks in advance for any answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the icon cache may need to be cleared. The terminal command you'll want to run is:

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
```

..and then log out and back in.